# Generate fingerprint with PGP Public Key

Tags: pgp, fingerprint, openpgp

I have a PGP public key and I need to get the fingerprint for it.

My Public key is as such:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
mQlDBF4w............................
.
.
.
=uYgH
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

I tried using the command `gpg --with-fingerprint key.txt` but it gives me the following output and there is no fingerprint in it:

```
gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...
pub   rsa4096 2020-01-28 [SC]
uid           cko_key <something@something.com>
sub   rsa4096 2020-01-28 [E]
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335669/gnupg-2-1-16-using-with-fingerprint-no-longer-shows-fingerprints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this answer for you and I believe it's the same issue you are having:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/448986/350132

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

The `--with-fingerprint` is an option, not a command. This option modifies the output of the `--list-keys` (for keys in the keyring) or `--show-keys` (for keys in files) command to include the fingerprint.

So the command you are looking for is

```
gpg --show-keys --with-fingerprint key.txt
```

If you need to process this further, e.g. from a script, you can also use the `--with-colons` option to get machine-readable output.

Note that there can be multiple keys in the output, and for the colon-separated output, multiple fingerprints even for a single key, because that also shows the fingerprints of subkeys.

Comment: I get the error below: gpg: invalid option "--show-keys"

Comment: I have `gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.12`, maybe you are using an older version?